# Unidentified method definition

Tags: c++

I am coding an infix to postfix algorithm that evaluates it as it goes. I am aware of how incredibly useless this program is, but the stack concepts etc make for a good academic project. So my method isOp() is called after I have split and parsed a line into tokens and I am checking to see if those tokens are operations, however it is not identifying that the function is defined, although I have written a definition for the function.

I have scanned the file for mismatching braces or any other syntax error that may be causing the error.

```
#ifndef INFIXEVALUATOR_H
#define INFIXEVALUATOR_H
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include "AStack.h"

using namespace std;

class Infix {
public:
    // constructors
    Infix();
    Infix(string e); // sets exp and calls eval();

                     //Accessors
    int getSolution() const; // returns solution
    string getExpression() const;  // returns the infix expression
    string results() const; // returns a string which is exp followed by " = " followed by solution

                            // mutator
    void setExpression(string e); // sets exp and calls eval()


private:

    void eval(); 
    void split();
    bool isOP(char c);
    bool lower(char op1, char op2); 
    void processTheOperator(); 

    string exp; 
    vector<string> tokens;
    AStack<int> numStack;
    AStack<char> charStack; 
    int solution; 


};

bool Infix::isOP(char c) {
    switch (c) {
    case '+':
    case '-':
    case '/':
    case '*': return true;
     return false;
    }
}


void Infix::eval() {
    numStack.clear();
    charStack.clear();
    tokens.clear();
    solution = 0;
    split();
    for (int i = 0; i < tokens.size(); i++) {
        if (isdigit(tokens[i][0])) {//push numbers
            numStack.push(stoi(tokens[i]));
        }
        else if (isOp(tokens[i][0])) {
            if (charStack.peek() == '(' || lower(charStack.peek(), tokens[i][0]) || charStack.isEmpty()) {//chcek to push right away
                charStack.push(tokens[i][0]);
            }
            .......
}
#endif
```

I left the definition of every function out of the stack Overflow post in order to minimize the code provided. In eval() when isOP(tokens[i][0]) is called in the else if statement the error I am getting is E0020 identifer "isOP" is undefined.

Comment: `isOP` != `isOp`. Pay attention to the capital `p` in your declaration and definition.

Comment: You have multiple namespace collisions, which is why you usually don't `using namespace std`

Answer (score 0):

`isOp()` should have an uppercase P.

Unrelated:

```
case '*': return true;
     return false;
}
```

Should probably be

```
case '*': return true;
default:
     return false;
}
```

Or

```
case '*': return true;
}
return false;
```